# UITableViewCell background image issue when the table scrolls up and comes back on that cell

Tags: uitableview, background, scroll, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm facing UITableViewCell setup issue when user scrolls down and up the table. The cell looses the changes (red/green background image set in `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath`) once the grouped-table scrolls to another cell and comes back to that cell.

I'm showing a question and 4 answer choices in two sections using the below code..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *kCustomCellID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CustomCellID%d", ((100 * indexPath.section) + indexPath.row)];

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;//[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCustomCellID] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = questionText;
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.textLabel.font = FONT_QUESTIONTEXT;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.answerChoices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.font = FONT_ANSWERTEXT;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        ConfigurationBase *configBase = [[ConfigurationBase alloc] initWithConfigurationType:kConfigTypeQuiz];

        NSString *backgroundImageName = [configBase.configInfo valueForKey:CKEY_IMG_ANSWER_BACKGROUND];
        NSString *leftImage = [configBase.configInfo valueForKey:[choicesLeftImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [configBase release];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        bgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:backgroundImageName];
        cell.backgroundView = bgView;
        [bgView release];

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:leftImage];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And, when the user selects one of the choice, I change the background color right and wrong selection with green and red color. The code for changing the background for 2 rows is below..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {   // Answer choice section.
        NSString *correctAnswerStr = [quizSession fetchCorrectAnswer];
        NSInteger correctAnswerIndex = -1;
        ConfigurationBase *configBase = [[ConfigurationBase alloc] initWithConfigurationType:kConfigTypeQuiz];

        NSString *correctAnsImageName = [configBase.configInfo valueForKey:CKEY_IMG_ANSWER_CORRECT_BACKGROUND];
        NSString *wrongAnsImageName = [configBase.configInfo valueForKey:CKEY_IMG_ANSWER_WRONG_BACKGROUND];
        [configBase release];

        UITableViewCell *answerCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        answerCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:answerCell.frame];
        bgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:wrongAnsImageName];
        answerCell.backgroundView = bgView;
        [bgView release];

        for (NSString *answerChoice in answerChoices) {
            ++correctAnswerIndex;

            if ([answerChoice isEqualToString:correctAnswerStr]) {
                // Correct Index obtained, so set the background color for it.
                NSIndexPath *correctIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:correctAnswerIndex
                                                                   inSection:indexPath.section];
                UITableViewCell *correctAnswerCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:correctIndexPath];

                correctAnswerCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:correctAnswerCell.frame];
                bgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:correctAnsImageName];
                correctAnswerCell.backgroundView = bgView;
                [bgView release];

                break;
            }
        }

        // Enable the 'next' button, allowing user to go for next question.
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
        // Disable selection of answer until user go to next question.
    tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
}
```

Can anyone help me on this? TIA.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of retrieving the information about the background image name is very complicated and error prone. Please make sure everything works as expected by inserting `NSLog`s at the appropriate places or checking in the debugger.

When dealing with the cell's `backgroundView` property you will have to put this code into `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` rather than in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. A simpler approach will save you time here again.